# How to make list if text present in text file

Tags: python, list, file, text, logic

Input text-
'''
Intro: hello, how are you
I am fine.

Intro: hey, how are you
Hope you are fine.
'''

Output:
[[hello,how are you i fine],[hey, how are you Hope you are fine]]

For text in f:
text= text.strip()

Comment: hey friend, your question is misleading in number of ways. Would encourage you to reframe it. Cannot understand -
1. why you want each string-lines to be again enclosed within a list.
2. If obvious, please specify how your data in your .txt file looks.
3. Please frame your question for better readability, would be helpful to .

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm unaware and confused about the structure of your .txt file, and framing of your question; still I would like to answer. Maybe it helps you.

Assuming the structure of your .txt file is supposedly like this screenshot -

[image]

Following code does the purpose -

```
f_list = []    ## final or output list

with open('sample-file.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_as_list = []       ## store `line` inside a list
        line_as_list.append(line.strip('Intro: ').strip())
        f_list.append(line_as_list)
```

`f_list` => [['hello, how are you I am fine.'], ['hey, how are you Hope you are fine.']]